# Having an SQLite database how to iterate thru all table items only knowing table name?

Tags: python, json, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I know table name, have SQLLite .db file. I want to not knowing its schema iterate thru an array of dictionaries (an item per each record containing pairs: `column name : data`). How to do such thing with sqlalchemy and python?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tablename;`? For SQLAlchemy you will need to have a model, which you might retrieve with [introspection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330013/sqlalchemy-introspection).

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: Please have a look at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html. You don't need a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this in Python:

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect("YourDatabase.db")
c=conn.cursor()
table=list(c.execute("""SELECT * FROM YourTable"""))
columns=list(c.execute("""PRAGMA table_info('YourTable')"""))
recordicts=[]
for record in table:
    dict1={}
    for i in range(len(record)):
        dict1.update({columns[i][1] : record[i]})
    recordicts.append(dict1)
print(recordicts)
```

Hope this helps! -Theo